# javascript: get value inside a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I finally managed to write a raw INSERT-query with sequelize/Apollo/ExpressJS and it returns a json like
`{"data":{"createActie":"[[{\"id\":1598}],1]"}}`.

I can get to [[{\"id\":1598}],1] by

```
await this.$apollo
            .mutate({
              mutation: CREATE_ACTIE_QUERY,
              variables: {
              // ...
              }
            })
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data.createActie);
            })
```

but now i want to extract the id and i struggle to say the least (i am not a trained javascript developer, just trying to learn by reading and experimenting)

Comment: try `console.log(response.data.createActie[0][0].id);`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I tried this already, but it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

the solution was adding json.parse...

```
JSON.parse(response.data.createActie)[0][0].id
```